# Can i run a single-task (mono-task) program on windows?

Tags: optimization, operating-system, multitasking, thread-priority

Hi 
 I did a project which is a little bit time consuming when executing, even after i optimisation of the code and set it to real-time execution (to assure that it takes its time share) and kill the max processes i don't need on *Windows 8.1*
I was wondering if there's a way to like freeze all the other processes and only run my program in monotask mode . So that i could use the full speed of my CPU ?
 *Note : I have an intel GPU (so parallel programming is a bit fuzzy for me) and  there isn't any multithread job i could call in all the algorithms which takes time to compute*
 Thank you for taking the time to understand my question

Comment: show what you did? this is not a homework site.

Comment: On Windows use [SetPriorityClass(REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Well @xmojmr i just mentioned that i ran it in realtime but thanks

Comment: @rootTraveller this is not some homework it's a complete project which takes time to execute but current operating systems are mostly multitask and i don't have enough time to port all my work to another OS so i just want to know if in windows environnement it's possible to fully use the cpu by running a process like if windows was a monotask OS that's all thanks

Comment: @Chekbo how much of one core are you using ATM?  If my system is reasonably idle, only, like 2-3% CPU is used up on sundry services and stuff like Skype etc.  That leaves 97% free for.. whatever.  If your app REALLY needs to use a lot of CPU to be used in an acceptable manner, just put it in your documentation that other CPU-intensive apps should not be run with it.

Comment: I mean, ' there isn't any multithread job i could call in all the algorithms which takes time to compute' - well, if your app has only one thread, why worry much about others running on the other cores?   I honestly don't understand your problem:(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit thanks for replying well my problem is that i want to be able to freeze everything else while my program is running i know that the os is well designed to use most of the power when it's needed but i have only one thread running sequencly and i want to run faster it's a mathematical computational problem it takes a lot of time calculating values and dynamic matrix and i just want to use it as if it was on an old console Os like dos or anything but just conceptually which means i want to freeze all the rest of the processes if it's possible